# How to create a maven Archetype from an existing archetype

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

Is it possible to create an application specific archetypes using an existing 'Generic' archetype?.

Generic Archetype - would contain the generic folders and config files etc. Extend the existing archetype to the child archetype.

Generic Archetype ---> Specific App Archetype (Keep app specific folders..)

Generic Archetype ---> Specific App Archetype 1

Every time when we create a project using application specific archetype should check for new updates in Generic archetype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me, you have **two** main choices :

1. You can create your own archetype from nothing. [Here is the official guide.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) You have few steps to follow (create a pom.xml, an archetype.xml,...).
2. You can create an archetype from an existing project folder. For example, first, you can create a project from a Maven archetype (like "maven-archetype-webapp") of a web application. Then, you make your changes (add or modify some configuration files, create a folder for a specific purpose, etc.). And finally, you can create you own archetype, from this project, executing this command line :

   mvn archetype:create-from-project

[A mini guide to create an archetype from a existing project.](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html)

[Reference doc to create an archetype from a existing project (mojo infos)](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment . But this won't work for my scenario. I would like to get the "Generic" archetype updates when I create a project using application specific archetype.